# Change Objective Function for Vehicle Routing Problem in Google's ortools

Tags: python, or-tools

I hope you are having a nice day.

I have a question about ortools published by Google in Python. ([Link](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/pickup_delivery))

I took a look at the functions and realized that the objective function is the total distance by default.

Is there any way to change the objective function into the other ones such as total tardiness or total arrival times?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't that be done by simply using time values in the distance matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a custom cost function, BUT the cost function can integrate:

- [mandatory] The sum of all arc cost used (used by any initial first strategy)
  ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/b37d9c786b69128f3505f15beca09e89bf078a89/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L901-L906
- [optional] The span cost of any dimension (e.d. one coefficient per vehicle, default 0)
- [optional] The global span cost of any dimension (e.d. one coefficient per dimension, default 0)
- [optional] A vehicle fixed cost (e.d. one cost per vehicle, default 0)
  ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/b37d9c786b69128f3505f15beca09e89bf078a89/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L907-L911
- [optional] A penalty cost for any dropping node using AddDisjunction() (default all nodes are mandatory)
  ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/b37d9c786b69128f3505f15beca09e89bf078a89/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L606-L624
- [optional] A linear penalty cost per node if using SoftCumulVar Lower/Upper Cost (to simulate earliness/tardiness) (default only hard limit [0, vehicle max capacity aka horizon of the dimension])
  ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/b37d9c786b69128f3505f15beca09e89bf078a89/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L2514-L2523
  ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/b37d9c786b69128f3505f15beca09e89bf078a89/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L2536-L2546

Misc/Not tested yet:

- [optional] Soft constraint a group of node to be visited by the same vehicle
  ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/b37d9c786b69128f3505f15beca09e89bf078a89/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L675-L679

note: You can search for "soft" which means add extra cost to objective if not fulfilled while hard constraint must be respected..

src: https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/YCUNTmWr8Us